# Django can not set AppConfig atrribute during ready()

Tags: django, python-3.x, configuration, settings

i'm currently trying to set a custom attribute for the AppConfig of one of my project's apps.

The point of doing so is, that the code producing the value needs to be run after App initialization. That's when i came accross the `ready()` method of AppConfig.

So suppose i got an app called `content` my apporach is :

```
from importlib import import_module

from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.conf import settings


class ContentConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "content"
    sone_val = None

    def ready(self):
        value = ... # some code
        if value:
            self.some_val = value
```

The `ready()` method gets called and at that point the value is correct. However when i try to access this attribute later in `views.py` via

```
from django.apps import apps as django_apps
django_apps.get_app_config("content").some_val
```

the result is `None` instead.

What am I overseeing/missunderstanding here?

Comment: I can not reproduce this. Are you sure the `value` has truthiness `True` (so it is not `False`, `()`, `''`, `None`, `[]`, etc.)

Comment: Well i figured it out in the meantime. Yes you are right it works but i couldn't see it due to some other issue i didn't know i had.